# sdf file in a wp8 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I am working on a WP8 application and it using sqlite db for storing application data.

I followed steps from the link http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone for doing the things .

But when I analyze my project files I can see one `Appname.sdf` file. How this one is getting created automatically (if I remove it, still it generates automatically when I open solution). Is there any good explanation on this available?

Comment: is it possible that you mean the intellisense database that is created by visual studio itself? is the sdf file in the solution folder?

Answer (score 0):

Just give a look at this code snippets in your reference link http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream output = iso.CreateFile(MainPage.DB_PATH))
   {
    // Initialize the buffer.
    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;

   // Copy the file from the installation folder to the local folder. 
   while ((bytesRead = input.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
      {
    output.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
      }
    }
```

When execute "using (IsolatedStorageFileStream output = iso.CreateFile(MainPage.DB_PATH))"  it creates a new file in isolated storage with no data.
Thats why you always get a db file in your application.